# Replace text place holders with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, text-manipulation

I have a text template that has text variables wrapped with {{ and }}.

I need a regular expression to gives me all the matches that "Include {{ and }}".

For example if I have {{FirstName}} in my text I want to get {{FirstName}} back as a match to be able to replace it with the actual variable.

I already found a regular expression that probably gives me what is INSIDE { and } but I don't know how can I modify it to return what I want.

```
/\{([^)]+)\}/
```

Comment: Does C# have a function similar to [`java.lang.String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern should do the trick:

```
string str = "{{FirstName}} {{LastName}}";

Regex rgx = new Regex("{{.*?}}");

foreach (var match in rgx.Matches(str))
{
    // {{FirstName}}
    // {{LastName}}
}
```

Comment: A better alternative is `Regex rgx = new Regex("{{.*?}}");`, and if the string in between braces is huge, you'd better consider unrolling it as `Regex rgx = new Regex("{{[^}]*(?:}(?!})[^}]*)*}}");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```js
alert(/^\{{2}[\w|\s]+\}{2}$/.test('{{FirstName}}'))
```

`^`: In the beginning.

`$`: In the end.

`\{{2}`: Character `{` 2 times.

`[\w|\s]+`: Alphabet characters or whitespace 1 or more times.

`\}{2}`: Character `}` 2 times.

**UPDATE:**

```js
alert(/(^\{{2})?[\w|\s]+(\}{2})?$/.test('FirstName'))
```

Comment: This will only match if **whole** string is like [`{{....}}`](https://regex101.com/r/vC6bQ2/1)

Comment: @tchelidze So, That's the reason I'm getting downvote?

Comment: Updated regex **only** matches [last occurrence](https://regex101.com/r/vC6bQ2/2). (*partially*)